# jasper report configuation -Message Could not connect via JDBC: Unable to start the

Tags: exception, types, report

Type Exception Report

Message Could not connect via JDBC: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Cannot get Connection from Datasource: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not connect via JDBC: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Cannot get Connection from Datasource: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

```
de.oc.utils.Utils.throwRuntimeException(Utils.java:18)
de.oc.db.ConnectionUtility.getConnection(ConnectionUtility.java:158)
de.oc.integration.jasper.webapp.AppConfig.getConnection(AppConfig.java:427)
de.oc.integration.jasper.webapp.ReportWrapper.service(ReportWrapper.java:248)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Type Exception Report

Message Could not connect via JDBC: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Cannot get Connection from Datasource: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not connect via JDBC: Unable to start the Universal Connection Pool: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: Cannot get Connection from Datasource: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor